# block title and body misaligned

Tags: beamer, posters, block

I'm making a poster with `beamer` and `beamer-poster` and I have a problem with my blocks.
The title and the body are misaligned.

[image]

This is a minimalist example :

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.9,debug]{beamerposter}

\title[my pres]{my pres}
\author[my name]{my name}
\institute[My home]{My home}
\date{29/05/2011}

\definecolor{couleurtexte}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{couleurconsole}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\vfill
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.25\linewidth}
\vbox to .95\textheight{%
\begin{block}{block 1}
\lipsum[1]%
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{block 2}%
\lipsum[1]%
\end{block}%
\vfill
\begin{block}{block 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item some items
\item some items
\item some items
\item some items
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the associated theme file :

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemetm1} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{firstcolor}{RGB}{0,68,255}
\definecolor{secondcolor}{RGB}{0,54,204}
\definecolor{thirdcolor}{RGB}{0,41,153}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{77,124,255}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=backgroundcolor}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=black,bg=firstcolor}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=couleurtexte, bg=firstcolor}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}

\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=couleurtexte}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=couleurtexte}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=couleurtexte}

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=couleurtexte, bg=ta2gray}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=couleurtexte, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=couleurtexte, bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=couleurtexte, bg=couleurtexte}
\setbeamercolor*{block begin}{bg=secondcolor,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block end}{bg=secondcolor,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=firstcolor,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=couleurtexte,bg=secondcolor}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
```

I think the problem is caused by the difference of font size in title and body (same sizes give a correct alignement)

**Do you know why I get this error and how to correct it ?**

Answer (score 2):

The beamer blocks are defined like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{block begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}% <-- LINE 1
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}% <-- LINE 2
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{block end}{default}  
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}
```

Responsible for the behavior you see is the `beamercolorbox` option `colsep` which is font size dependent. So what you want to do is redefine the block begin templates with an font size independent measure (like mm for example):

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=2mm]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=2mm,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```